# Open StreetMap Marker example

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I am trying to plot a movable marker on an "Open Street map"

```
<html><body>
   <div id="mapdiv"></div>
    <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script>
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
    var zoom=16;

var marker = new khtml.maplib.overlay.Marker({
    position: new khtml.maplib.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922), 
    map: map,
    title:"static marker"
});

map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);
</script>
</body></html>
```

and I am getting this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: khtml is not defined
```

how can I solve it , and is there any missing javascript file that I need to include ?
knowing that I refered to [marker API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Marker_API)

Comment: Basically, you need to load [this](https://github.com/robotnic/khtmlib) javascript framework.